# Can JavaScript inserted into a Script string be called as normal by a WebBrowser object?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control

I may not be asking that question correctly but I have a WebBrowser that has pretty verbose script inside it.
I'm using some string manipulation to insert my own JavaScript string into it (just a simple window.external.(); line), hoping that it will call it, but so far, it hasn't.

Like so:

```
    string script = <WebBrowserObject>.Document.GetElementsByTagName("script")[3].InnerText;
    script = script.Insert(script.IndexOf(<Line to place function call after>) + <length of that line>, <string variable holding my function call>);
    <WebBrowserObject>.Document.GetElementsByTagName("script")[3].InnerText = script;
```

There's a JavaScript function that fires repeatedly that I need to be in sync with a form display that shows a countdown timer.

And I have also:

```
    <WebBrowserObject>.ObjectForScripting = this;
```

There hasn't been a JavaScript error shown, and I've been able to tie in a JavaScript like response by adding the window.external.(); line to an input buttons onclick attribute and seen results. Right now the only thing the function is supposed to do is write a line to the output window to make sure it works.
Is this method the correct method to achieve this desired result? Does anyone have a better way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, once the contents of a script tag have been run, you can't run it again (you might be able to reset it's flag regarding if the contents have run or not but I'm sure if that exists, that's a browser specific thing) .  What I think you need to do is to add a new script tag with the code you want inside of it.  If the WebBrowser control's interface is anything like you'd do in javascript when interfacing with the DOM, you can create a script element, add your text to the element, and then attach it somewhere to the DOM (like the `head`) an then it should run.

In pure javascript, it'd be something like.

```
var head1 = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
var script1 = document.createElement('script');
script1.innerText = "alert('hey');"; //javascript to run.
head1.appendChild(script1)
```

Of course, when you're done, you probably ought to `h1111.removeChild(script111)` just to keep the DOM from accumulating scripts....  I don't know if there's anything special about when it's safe to remove the script tag in certain browsers... you might get away with removing it immediately (I just seem to have some vague and maybe incorrect recollection about reading some case where it is advisable to wait a little bit).